# Odd behaviour when slicing Pandas dataframe with numeric column headings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have a Pandas dataframe containing case-control data and can be represented by the following structure:

```
   caseA  caseN catA
0      y      1    a
1      y      1    a
2      y      1    b
3      y      1    b
4      y      1    c
5      y      1    d
6      y      1    a
7      y      1    c
8      n      0    c
9      n      0    d
10     n      0    a
11     n      0    b
12     n      0    c
13     n      0    a
14     n      0    d
15     n      0    a
16     n      0    b
17     n      0    c
18     n      0    a
19     n      0    d
```

The caseA and caseN variables represent cases and controls as strings and integers, respectively.

I can calculate a 2x2 table to facilitate the calculation of odds and odds ratios using the pandas crosstab method. The default order of the columns is control-case but I change this to case-control which, to my way of thinking, is a bit more intuitive.

I then slice the dataframe to print just a select number of rows with columns in the order case - control. This works exactly as expected.

However, if I add a new column to the dataframe (e.g. a column containing the odds values) and then slice the dataframe in exactly the same way, the cases and controls are printed in the wrong order.

The following code snippet illustrates this point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'caseN':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'caseA':['y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n'],
                   'catA':['a','a','b','b','c','d','a','c','c','d','a','b','c','a','d','a','b','c','a','d']})

print('\nCross tabulation\n')
continTab = pd.crosstab(df['catA'],df['caseN'])
print(continTab)

print('\nReorderd cross tabulation\n')
continTab = continTab[[1,0]]
print(continTab)

#print('\n<-- An extra column containg odds has been entered here -->')
#continTab['odds'] = continTab[1]/continTab[0]

print('\nPrint just a slice contains rows a and c only with 1 - 0 column order\n')
print(continTab.loc[['a','c'],[1,0]])
```

On the first run through the sliced table produced is just as expected:

```
caseN  1  0
catA       
a      3  4
c      2  3
```

But if you uncomment the code that calculates the odds column and then re-run the exact same code, the sliced table produced is:

```
caseN  0  1
catA       
a      4  3
c      3  2
```

I can think of no reason when this should happen. Is this a bug?

(Interestingly, repeating the process using the case-control data described as strings (in variable caseA) produces the correct expected results.)

Comment: Worth asking this question here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: I think you're right. Done.